# Trying to add mutliple params to AddDbContext<T>'s UseSqlServer but can't

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do this:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
                opt => opt.UseSqlServer(
                    configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnectionString"),
                x => x.UseNetTopologySuite(),
                options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure())); // Here's where it fails
```

But I'm getting this:
`No overload for method UseSqlServer takes 3 arguments`

I understand that however I don't know how to do it any other way besides going down a path I don't know.

Comment: You're telling us you're trying to achieve something and you're doing it incorrectly. Please also tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the configuration method calls like so:

```
x => x.UseNetTopologySuite().EnableRetryOnFailure()
```

Comment: You're a legend. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
    opt => opt.UseSqlServer(
        configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnectionString"),
        options => options
            .UseNetTopologySuite()
            .EnableRetryOnFailure()
        )
    );
```